# How to build an executable with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, exe

**I am wondering if there is a way to make executable using just javascript**

Answer (score 1):

Check ElectronJS where you can build nodejs executable [Electronjs](https://electronjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out.
[github/nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe)